# What is a good naming convention for vars, methods, etc in C++?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I come from a the Objective-C and Cocoa world where there are lots of conventions and many people will say it makes your code beautiful!
Now programming in C++ I cannot find a good document like this one for C++.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html

Standard C++ probably does not have something like above but I hope I can stick to some other SDK or APIs (like Microsoft's(?),etc) conventions.

I hope you can provide me with some links.

Comment: I promise to downvote anyone who suggests Hungarian.

Comment: @AShelly: read up Joel Spoolsky post on Hungarian Notation and it may change your mind. I do disagree with him, but the post is worthwhile nonetheless as it explains the HUGE misunderstanding on this scheme.

Comment: I promise to downvote anyone who suggest the Google conventions.

Comment: @Matthieu: What Joel suggests is good for C, but if you're using C++ and is serious about the things Joel suggests you can get the compiler to catch when you for instance mistakenly try to convert a row to a column (which I believe was what he used as an example).

Comment: @Andreas: yes, and that is why I disagree with him, I prefer to use the type system itself rather than tack arbitrary (and obscure) letters before my identifiers (apart from the `m` for members of my classes). If I remember he used both row/columns and safe/unsafe strings.

Comment: @Matthieu: I had read it, and I support the goal of 'making wrong code look wrong'.  I should have specified that I oppose "Systems Hungarian" which does not serve that purpose, or any other purpose that I can see.

Comment: @AShelly: we agree :) Systems Hungarian is useless (it just adds clutter). I am of opinion that Apps Hungarian doesn't really help much though, and I much prefer to enforce proper code through proper typing than with a "proper" naming convention. Compilers are systemic in their analysis.

Comment: @Philipp: Why, because of the no-exceptions suggestions? Something else?

Comment: I'd like to add to this question; a convention that stands out to be a bit unusual is using PascalCase/upper camelCase for method names. Where does this come from?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Do whatever you want as long as its minimal, consistent, and [doesn't break any rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Personally, I find the Boost style easiest; it matches the standard library (giving a uniform look to code) and is simple. I personally tack on `m` and `p` prefixes to members and parameters, respectively, giving:

```
#ifndef NAMESPACE_NAMES_THEN_PRIMARY_CLASS_OR_FUNCTION_THEN_HPP
#define NAMESPACE_NAMES_THEN_PRIMARY_CLASS_OR_FUNCTION_THEN_HPP

#include <boost/headers/go/first>
#include <boost/in_alphabetical/order>
#include <then_standard_headers>
#include <in_alphabetical_order>

#include "then/any/detail/headers"
#include "in/alphabetical/order"
#include "then/any/remaining/headers/in"
// (you'll never guess)
#include "alphabetical/order/duh"

#define NAMESPACE_NAMES_THEN_MACRO_NAME(pMacroNames) ARE_ALL_CAPS

namespace lowercase_identifers
{
    class separated_by_underscores
    {
    public:
        void because_underscores_are() const
        {
            volatile int mostLikeSpaces = 0; // but local names are condensed

            while (!mostLikeSpaces)
                single_statements(); // don't need braces

            for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                but_multiple(i);
                statements_do();
            }             
        }

        const complex_type& value() const
        {
            return mValue; // no conflict with value here
        }

        void value(const complex_type& pValue)
        {
            mValue = pValue ; // or here
        }

    protected:
        // the more public it is, the more important it is,
        // so order: public on top, then protected then private

        template <typename Template, typename Parameters>
        void are_upper_camel_case()
        {
            // gman was here                
        }

    private:
        complex_type mValue;
    };
}

#endif
```

That.
(And like I've said in comments, do *not* adopt the Google Style Guide for your code, unless it's for something as inconsequential as naming convention.)

Comment: Hey! you sneak in your brace-style preference! Personally I much prefer to have braces even for one-line statements, it's easy to screw up the indentation (when people inadvertently edit with another tab/space settings) and braces make the scope evident so you don't wonder whether or not the following line was meant to belong to the block or not...

Comment: +1 : Yeah, that's the style I use in my own projects. INCLUDING the brace style preference ;)

Comment: Mine is similar. The only difference. Types start with an uppercase letter. Everything else starts with a lower case letter (just my quirk).

Comment: @Martin, curiosity -- so types still use underscores and capitals? Class_name_like_this or Class_Name_Like_This?

Comment: @Matthieu: Ha, I wouldn't pass the opportunity up. :) I used to religiously defend having braces always, but nowadays I find it cleaner to omit them. (Typically the single statements are `return;` or something trivial).

Comment: @GMan: So do I when I am working alone, but when I have to share my work I prefer to be as explicit as possible, including for one-line blocks. However I do put them inline: `if (cond) { return xxx; }` if possible.

Comment: I agree with Matthieu. Always use braces!! When I was young and naïve I hated braces, which I thought cluttered up my codez. Now when I'm older and wiser I live by the rule to always make my intentions clear. Putting braces around one-liners is one part of doing just that.

Comment: I 've been looking for a document about Boost naming conventions and only could find this: http://www.boost.org/development/requirements.html Did you learn it by using it or maybe read something?

Comment: @Gman: for one-liners I prefer to keep the braces, and just put it on a single line, as Matthieu showed. It's even shorter, and it's explicit and I don't have to worry about messing up if I add another line to the body.

Comment: really like this one; I'd only switch the class and the local variables. i.e. class with cases, locals with underscore.

Answer (score 30):

There are probably as many naming conventions as there are individuals, the debate being as endless (and sterile) as to which brace style to use and so forth.

So I'll have 2 advices:

- be **consistent** within a project
- don't use reserved identifiers (anything with two underscores or beginning with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter)

The rest is up to you.

Comment: +1 for "be consistent"; that's the single most important rule of the lot (and the only one that you'll probably get everyone to agree with).

Comment: +1 reserved identifiers, just cos the compiler isnt using it now doesn't mean the next version won't

Answer (score 27):

I actually often use Java style: PascalCase for type names, camelCase for functions and variables, CAPITAL_WORDS for preprocessor macros. I prefer that over the Boost/STL conventions because you don't have to suffix types with `_type`. E.g.

```
Size size();
```

instead of

```
size_type size();   // I don't like suffixes
```

This has the additional benefit that the StackOverflow code formatter recognizes `Size` as a type name ;-)

Comment: very good example, much better clarity and readability

Answer (score 14):

We follow the guidelines listed on this page: [C++ Programming Style Guidelines](http://geosoft.no/development/cppstyle.html)

---

I'd also recommend you read [The Elements of C++ Style by Misfeldt et al](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521893089), which is quite an excellent book on this topic.

Comment: Can I use the document referenced in your FIRST link as the guideline document in a project that I am starting?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli, yes sure.

Comment: Thanks!, much appreciated! (should make life easier too)!. Incidentally, is there any attribution I should make at the bottom of the text etc? - if yes, who do I attribute?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli, I am not affiliated with that page/document. I'd suggest including a link to the page if you find it helpful and decide to use it.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards

Answer (score 7):

For what it is worth, Bjarne Stroustrup, the original author of C++ has his own favorite style, described here: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html

Answer (score 3):

While many people will suggest more or less strict [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) variants ([scary](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)!), for naming suggestions I'd suggest you take a look at [Google C++ Coding Guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml). This may well be not the most popular naming conventions, but at least it's fairly complete. Apart from sound naming conventions, there's some useful guidelines there, however much of it should be taken with a grain of salt (exception ban for example, and the tendency to keep away from modern C++ coding style).

Although personally I like the extreme low-tech convention style of STL and Boost ;).

Comment: Google's C++ Coding Guidelines are awful, do not adopt them. (Except anything as inconsequential as naming conventions.) The Google style guide is the antithesis of good modern C++ code.

Comment: @GMan: I agree, Google guidelines are meant specifically to be backward compatible with their existing C code base (as is mentioned explicitly in the guidelines). For a new project, they are one of the worst thing that could happen.

Comment: @GMan, that's what I initially thought too, but more careful study of the document made me realize that it strikes a good balance between leaving some room to breathe to pros and (more importantly) not allowing newbie developers to blow themselves up. You can't count on having a team of good modern C++ coders anywhere -- and even one bad coder can ruin a good codebase without strict guidelines...

Comment: @GMan: could you explicit what you find awful in the Google guidelines ? I'm reading it right now and some advices seem pretty good.

Comment: I have not seen anybody seriously suggest Hungarian notation in twenty years. The only time it is mentioned is as the antitheses of what you should do. PS. You need to read the Google standard again (for any new project it should not be used unless you want backward compatibility with google's original code.).

Comment: @ereOn: It says don't use exceptions. What do you think is good? I mean a lot of it is boilerplate. But when it deviates it deviates.

Comment: @Martin, I agree that the exceptions clause is ridiculous ;)

Comment: @Martin York: Actually, I hadn't read that part yet... indeed, some advices are terrible. (And especially this one, yes) For what I found good, was all the "common-sense" advices regarding variable lifetime. But I realize it is not exactly specific to Google.

Comment: @Kornel: Modern C++ doesn't mean hard C++.

Comment: @GMan, so do I think, but for the time I was working at a corporation coding in C++ it was next to impossible to enforce in any way Modern C++...

Comment: @GManNickG: SO what else is wrong, to your view, with Google's guidelines other than no-exceptions?

Comment: @einpoklum: I don't really feel like walking through it, but in general it advocates for "C with classes" rather than C++. Now that I actually work at Google (I didn't when I first made that comment), I see these effects. The code is more difficult than it needs to be because the style guide bans the simpler options. As everyone points out, these choices are basically made to strike a balance between needing to be an expert to understand the code and getting work done properly, but seeing as C++ is expert-friendly I generally don't agree with artificial hand-holding.

Comment: @GManNickG: Could you link to somewhere explaining this in a little more detail perhaps (as I don't quite follow)?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different sytles/conventions that people use when coding C++. For example, some people prefer separating words using capitals (myVar or MyVar), or using underscores (my_var). Typically, variables that use underscores are in all lowercase (from my experience).
There is also a coding style called hungarian, which I believe is used by microsoft. I personally believe that it is a waste of time, but it may prove useful. This is were variable names are given short prefixes such as i, or f to hint the variables type. For example: int iVarname, char* strVarname.

It is accepted that you end a struct/class name with _t, to differentiate it from a variable name. E.g.:

```
class cat_t {
  ...
};

cat_t myCat;
```

It is also generally accepted to add a affix to indicate pointers, such as pVariable or variable_p.

In all, there really isn't any single *standard*, but many. The choices you make about naming your variables doesn't matter, so long as it is understandable, and above all, consistent. Consistency, consistency, CONSISTENCY! (try typing that thrice!)

And if all else fails, google it.

Comment: Naming **every** class with an ending '_t' would be downright evil...

Comment: It is used for classes used as data types.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz probably classes used as domain objects (very late reply). `std::string` is a data type (and is used similarly to `int` or `double`); `bank_account` is a domain object (and is not).

Answer (score 1):

consistency and readability (self-documenting code) are important. some clues (such as case) can and should be used to avoid collisions, and to indicate whether an instance is required.

one of the best practices i got into was the use of code formatters (astyle and uncrustify are 2 examples). code formatters can destroy your code formatting - configure the formatter, and let it do its job. seriously, forget about manual formatting and get into the practice of using them. they will save a ton of time.

as mentioned, be very descriptive with naming. also, be very specific with scoping (class types/data/namespaces/anonymous namespaces). in general, i really like much of java's common written form - that is a good reference and similar to c++.

as for specific appearance/naming, this is a small sample similar to what i use (variables/arguments are lowerCamel and this only demonstrates a portion of the language's features):

```
/** MYC_BEGIN_FILE_ID::FD_Directory_nanotimer_FN_nanotimer_hpp_::MYC_BEGIN_FILE_DIR::Directory/nanotimer::MYC_BEGIN_FILE_FILE::nanotimer.hpp::Copyright... */
#ifndef FD_Directory_nanotimer_FN_nanotimer_hpp_
#define FD_Directory_nanotimer_FN_nanotimer_hpp_

/* typical commentary omitted -- comments detail notations/conventions. also, no defines/macros other than header guards */

namespace NamespaceName {

/* types prefixed with 't_' */
class t_nanotimer : public t_base_timer {
    /* private types */
    class t_thing {
        /*...*/
    };
public:
    /* public types */
    typedef uint64_t t_nanosecond;

    /* factory initializers -- UpperCamel */
    t_nanotimer* WithFloat(const float& arg);
    /* public/protected class interface -- UpperCamel */
    static float Uptime();
protected:
    /* static class data -- UpperCamel -- accessors, if needed, use Get/Set prefix */
    static const t_spoke Spoke;
public:
    /* enums in interface are labeled as static class data */
    enum { Granularity = 4 };
public:
    /* construction/destruction -- always use proper initialization list */
    explicit t_nanotimer(t_init);
    explicit t_nanotimer(const float& arg);

    virtual ~t_nanotimer();

    /*
       public and protected instance methods -- lowercaseCamel()
       - booleans prefer is/has
       - accessors use the form: getVariable() setVariable().
       const-correctness is important
     */
    const void* address() const;
    virtual uint64_t hashCode() const;
protected:
    /* interfaces/implementation of base pure virtuals (assume this was pure virtual in t_base_timer) */
    virtual bool hasExpired() const;
private:
    /* private methods and private static data */
    void invalidate();
private:
    /*
       instance variables
       - i tend to use underscore suffix, but d_ (for example) is another good alternative
       - note redundancy in visibility
     */
    t_thing ivar_;
private:
    /* prohibited stuff */
    explicit t_nanotimer();
    explicit t_nanotimer(const int&);
};
} /* << NamespaceName */
/* i often add a multiple include else block here, preferring package-style inclusions */    
#endif /* MYC_END_FILE::FD_Directory_nanotimer_FN_nanotimer_hpp_ */
```

Comment: You definitely love lowercase ;D

Comment: @bluish …and dislike collisions :)

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter.  Just make sure you name your variables and functions descriptively. Also be consistent.

Nowt worse than seeing code like this:

```
int anInt;                  // Great name for a variable there ...
int myVar = Func( anInt );  // And on this line a great name for a function and myVar
                            // lacks the consistency already, poorly, laid out!
```

Edit:  As pointed out by my commenter that consistency needs to be maintained across an entire team.  As such it doesn't matter WHAT method you chose, as long as that consistency is maintained.  There is no right or wrong method, however.  Every team I've worked in has had different ideas and I've adapted to those.

Comment: It DOES matter. You talk like you'd never have worked in a team before.

Comment: Well it DOESN'T matter as long as its descriptive and consistent ... Yes in a team that means maintaining that consistency across a whole team.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

not nearly as concise as the link you provided: but the following chapter 14 - 24 may help :) hehe

ref: [http://www.amazon.com/Coding-Standards-Rules-Guidelines-Practices/dp/0321113586/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1284443869&sr=8-1-catcorr](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586)

Comment: Just skimmed through it, and it's hardly anything about naming there (except the obvious_like_dont_do_too_long_and_useless_variable_names...)

Comment: doooh... you're right. i was thinking "structural" convention rather than naming convention because i wasn't trying to understand your question and reading the link you provided.

Comment: This book is about elements of programming style that help to improve code quality, and irrelevant details like naming conventions are summed up in Item 0: Don't Sweat The Small Stuff (or: Know What Not To Standardise). It won't help if you feel the need to standardise the irrelevent details.