# Creating a C++ vector iterator for a vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct, types, iterator

I've declared a struct outside the main() function (with a few operator overloads for it).

I made a vector of the structs in the main() and then passed it by reference to another function.(node is the struct)

```
void openInsert(vector<node> &vec, node node)//insert nodes in least to greatest
```

I need to iterate over the the vector. I was trying to use a iterator but I'm getting an error when declaring it.
(im using "using namespace std;")

```
vector<node>::iterator itr = vec.begin();
```

the error is :

```
 no suitable user-defined conversion from  
 "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<node>>>" to 
 "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<<error-type>>>>" exists
```

also :

```
parameter "node" is not a type name
```

Comment: Having both a type named `node`, and a function parameter named `node` (whose type is `node`), can only bring you a major world of hurt.

Comment: capitalize your type name, `struct Node` or `class Node`

Comment: this is embarrassing thank you for the correction changing the name worked,  why should i capitalize?

Comment: @ColemanPlatt, several reasons. (1) You're Coleman Platt, not e e cummings (and even he occasionally used capitalization). (2) It's an extremely widely used convention. (3) It's a simple convention, that if followed, never results in a collision between a type name and a variable name, or between a type name and a function name.

Comment: @DavidHammen I agree it’s better to follow widely-used conventions like this one, but I disagree with point 1. The English convention there is to capitalize a person’s name, not the word “human”; it breaks the programming convention.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 0):

Your error stems from `node node` on the line

```
void openInsert(vector<node> &vec, node node)//insert nodes in least to greatest
```

In general it is not a good idea to have a type with the same name as a variable. It can lead to difficult to debug issues like this where the compiler is confused about whether you mean `node` the type or `node` the variable.

Common (and best) practice is to start your class and struct names with a capital letter. Changing the `node` type to `Node` will change the problem line to

```
void openInsert(vector<Node> &vec, Node node)//insert nodes in least to greatest
```

which should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are [following a naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706379/what-is-a-good-naming-convention-for-vars-methods-etc-in-c) with small letters for class names, then name clashes can be avoided by using namespaces

```
#include <vector>

namespace mp{

class node{};

}

// when refering to the class, prefix with mp::
// when refering to a variable name, don't.
void foo(std::vector<mp::node>& vec, mp::node node){
    std::vector<mp::node>::iterator itr = vec.begin();
}
```

[compilable example on ideone](https://ideone.com/RrkjgQ)