# C++ QThread and connect causing crashes

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface, qt5

My QThread counter crashes giving odd results for what the number should be as the Thread counts properly but in the SetLabel function I get a different number to whats in the QThread ands it then crashes after 3 seconds and the label doesnt seem to update.

```
QThread* CountThread = new QThread;
Counter* Count = new Counter();
Count->moveToThread(CountThread);
connect(CountThread, SIGNAL(started()), Count, SLOT(Process()));
connect(Count, &Counter::SecondsUpdate, this, [=]{ SetLabel(Count->Seconds) ;});
connect(Count, SIGNAL(finished()), CountThread, SLOT(quit()));
CountThread->start();


void Counter::Process()
{
int secs = 0;
while (secs < 1000)
{
    qDebug() << "hello" << secs;
    secs += 1;
    Sleep(1000);
    emit SecondsUpdate();
}
emit finished();
}


void BaseWindow::SetLabel(int Seconds)
{
qDebug() << Seconds;
this->Test->setText(QString("Seconds: " + QString::number(Seconds)));
}

class Counter : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void Process();

signals:
    void finished();
    void SecondsUpdate();

public:
    int getValue() { return Seconds;}
    int Seconds;

};
```

EDIT: The issue seems to lie in the changing of the label as I commented this->Text->setText out and it didnt crash

Comment: @eyllanesc its just a sleep function from windows.h

Comment: what is `Count->Seconds`??

Comment: @eyllanesc 

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void Process();

signals:
    void finished();
    void SecondsUpdate();

public:
    int getValue() { return Seconds;}
    int Seconds;

};

Comment: please edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @eyllanesc done

Comment: Also note that `Counter::Process` never updates `Counter::Seconds`.

Comment: @G.M.oooh that would make sense. It still crashes the program however.

Comment: You're also (in the lambda) accessing `Count->Seconds` from a thread *other* than that associated with `Count`.

Comment: @mrdeadguy34 
I'm in Linux so change Sleep() to QThread::Sleep(), although your implementation is not the most elegant I have implemented it and it does not generate any errors, you could take the time and provide a decent [mcve], besides using a debugger.

Comment: @G.M. How would I fix that?

Comment: @mrdeadguy34 just a nit-pick (as I am sure this is simply a test program), but for the record I am obligated to mention standard coding convention names, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706453/4628115 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706598/4628115

Comment: Get rid of the SIGNAL and SLOT macro's they will only bite you runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown has two basic problems.

1. `Counter::Seconds` is never initialized/updated.
2. Having moved `Count` to a new `QThread` you continue to access it from the main thread.

You could solve both of these by getting rid of the `Seconds` member and just passing the local counter `secs` as a parameter to the `Counter::SecondsUpdate` signal...

```
class Counter: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT;
public slots:
  void Process();
signals:
  void finished();
  void SecondsUpdate(int seconds);
public:
};

void Counter::Process ()
{
  int secs = 0;
  while (secs < 1000)
  {
    qDebug() << "hello" << secs;
    secs += 1;

    /*
     * Sleep(1000) --> QThread::sleep(1)
     */
    QThread::sleep(1);

    /*
     * Pass secs as a parameter to the SecondsUpdate signal.
     */
    emit SecondsUpdate(secs);
  }
  emit finished();
}
```

Then, change the relevant `connect` call from...

```
connect(Count, &Counter::SecondsUpdate, this, [=]{ SetLabel(Count->Seconds) ;});
```

to...

```
connect(Count, &Counter::SecondsUpdate, this, &BaseWindow::SetLabel);
```

Comment: change `connect(Count, &Counter::SecondsUpdate, this,
        [=](int seconds)
        {
          SetLabel(seconds);
        });` to `connect(Count, &Counter::SecondsUpdate, this, &BaseWindow::SetLabel)`, is more elegant

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Looks great to me!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by passing through the label as a pointer and edited it in the function.